# How to invert animation order in react-spring's useTransitions

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

I want to animate the opacity of the items from number 1 to 4, but want to run it inverted (from 4 to 1) if the items are removed. I thought that the `reverse` flag could help, but it doesn't do anything:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { animated, config, useTransition } from "react-spring";

export default function App() {
  const items = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  const [isToggled, setToggled] = useState(false);

  const transitions = useTransition(isToggled ? items : [], item => item, {
    config: config.gentle,
    unique: true,
    trail: 250,
    reverse: isToggled ? false : true,
    from: { opacity: 0 },
    enter: { opacity: 1 },
    leave: { opacity: 0 }
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setToggled(!isToggled)}>Toggle</button>

      {transitions.map(({ item, key, props }) => (
        <animated.div key={key} style={props}>
          Issue #{item}
        </animated.div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-leavitt-l49iy)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `reverse` method is it reverse all the content inside the array.
You only need to `reverse` the `props` properties inside the result of your `useTransition`.

With simple array modification like this (in typescript) :

```js
// utils/animation.ts
// or js just modify the type

import { UseTransitionResult } from 'react-spring';

export function reverseTransition<T, Result extends UseTransitionResult<T, object>>(
  arr: Result[],
): Result[] {
  const result: Result[] = [];
  for (let idx = 0; idx < arr.length; idx++) {
    result.push({
      ...arr[idx],
      props: arr[arr.length - 1 - idx].props,
    });
  }
  return result;
}
```

and pass the result of useTransition hooks like this :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { animated, config, useTransition } from "react-spring";

// import above code
import { reverseTransition } from "utils/animation";

export default function App() {
  const items = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  const [isToggled, setToggled] = useState(false);

  const transitions = useTransition(isToggled ? items : [], item => item, {
    config: config.gentle,
    unique: true,
    trail: 250,
    reverse: isToggled ? false : true,
    from: { opacity: 0 },
    enter: { opacity: 1 },
    leave: { opacity: 0 }
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setToggled(!isToggled)}>Toggle</button>

      {(isToggled ? transitions : reverseTransition(transitions)).map(({ item, key, props }) => (
        <animated.div key={key} style={props}>
          Issue #{item}
        </animated.div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You will get the reversed animation with the same content.
I hope it helps!

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-reverse-transition-3e9ut)

**Notes: I am using React Spring v8, not v9 (the one that you use in your Codesandbox)**

Regards